# minus row return for updating table sql

Tags: sql

I'm pretty new to more complex SQL and cannot get this code to update properly

```
$sql = "UPDATE bank_accounts
    SET bank_accounts.balance = bank_accounts.balance - upgrades.cost 
    FROM upgrades
    INNER JOIN upgrades AS u
    WHERE u.id = :id
    AND
    bank_accounts.uid = :uid"

;
```

Comment: What for do you JOIN upgrades to upgrades itself?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things...

1. Where is the :id and :uid coming from?
2. If you alias upgrades as 'u' then you always have to use 'u', so you can't type 'upgrades.cost'.  It should be 'u.cost'.
3. Also you listed 'upgrades' twice in the FROM clause.

Try this maybe?

```
$sql = "UPDATE bank_accounts
          SET bank_accounts.balance = bank_accounts.balance - u.cost 
        FROM upgrades u INNER JOIN bank_accounts
             ON u.id = back_accounts.id";
```

Another thought...
updates make me nervous, so I always like to do a SELECT on the data before doing an update.

```
SELECT bank_accounts.balance as BEFORE, bank_accounts.balance - u.cost as AFTER
FROM bank_accounts, upgrades u
     ON u.id = bank_accounts.id
```